# Why does my transformation sending $0$ to $w$ change in these Möbius transforms?

Tags: group-theory, complex-analysis

My first question is:

> Let $M_{\alpha}, \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, be the subgroup of $M$ mapping $\alpha$ to itself, that is, the stabilizer of $\alpha$. Given that
>
> $$M_0 = \left \{w = \frac{z}{cz + d}, d \neq 0 \right \}$$
>
> compute the subgroup $M_i, i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Here, $L$ is the transformation sending $0$ to $i$ i,e $L : z \mapsto z + i$

The second one is

> Compute the subgroup $M_{\{0, -3, \infty\}} \subset M$ consisting of 6 transformations, preserving the set $\{0, -3, \infty\}$, together with an explicit isomorphism
>
> $$M_{\{0, -3, \infty\}} = S_3$$

Here, my $L: z \mapsto -3z$

In the second one, why does $z \mapsto -3z$ and not $z \mapsto z - 3$ (and therefore why does $z \mapsto z + i$ in the first one)?

Comment: What do you mean by "My $L$ is"? What is this $L$? Are you referring to some method of solution you were taught? In this case, you should state explicitly what this method is.

Comment: My $L$ was what I thought $L$ should be. In the first question, $L$ is the transformation sending $0$ to $i$.

Comment: Sorry what do you need $L$ for?? It doesn't appear in the statement of the problem...

Comment: @wisefool To do question 1 for example, I get what the transformation $L$ is and then the subgroup is given by $M_i = L \circ M_0 \circ L^{-1}$

Comment: Ok, and in problem 2? what do you use $L$ for? Which group plays the role of $M_0$?

Comment: In 2, I thought it would be $L : z \mapsto z - 3$ but it is $L : z \mapsto -3z$, the question I am asking is why? I'm not sure what $M_0$ would just be all the permutations which I can do this question for the set $\{0, 1, \infty\}$ but as I don't know them, I used a different method.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you want to find $M_i$ given $M_0$. There is a bijection between $M_0$ and $M_i$ given by $T \mapsto L\circ T\circ L^{-1}$ where $L$ is any Möbius transformation such that $L(0) = i$; as you note, $L(z) = z + i$ is one such transformation.

For the second case, you want to find $M_{\{0, -3, \infty\}}$ given $M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}}$. As before, there is a bijection between $M_{\{0, -3, \infty\}}$ given $M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}}$ given by $T \mapsto L\circ T\circ L^{-1}$ where $L$ is any Möbius transformation such that $L(\{0, 1, \infty\}) = \{0, -3, \infty\}$. For $L(z) = z - 3$, we have $L(\{0, 1, \infty\}) = \{-3, -2, \infty\} \neq \{0, -3, \infty\}$. However, if we choose $L(z) = -3z$ then $L(\{0, 1, \infty\}) = \{0, -3, \infty\}$.

In general, for $a, b, c$ distinct, there is a bijection between $M_{\{0, 1, \infty\}}$ and $M_{\{a, b, c\}}$ given by $T \mapsto L\circ T\circ L^{-1}$ where $L$ is any Mobius transformation satisfying $L(\{0, 1, \infty\}) = \{a, b, c\}$; note, for any choice of distinct $a, b, c$, such an $L$ exists.